# Don't know the equation in an SMBC comic.

Tags: reference-request

The comic is [here](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=3058#comic).  The equation is: $$ L\left(q\,, \dot{q}\,,t\right) = \mbox{everything}$$

I have tried searching for it, but haven't found it. So I am asking here.

Comment: As Unreasonable Sin has indicated, it indeed refers to the Lagrangian.  A related link that this might be referencing is the Standard Model Lagrangian, which can be found here: http://nuclear.ucdavis.edu/~tgutierr/files/stmL1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from Lagrangian mechanics. $q$ is a generalized coordinate and $\dot{q}$ is its derivative with respect to time $t$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian